# cordova-admob-pro not working with cordova 8 and android 7.1.0

Tags: android, cordova, admob

I'm using [cordova-admob-pro plugin](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro) to show ads on my apps, lately google announced that updates to apps android are requred to target android oreo (API level 26) or higher. so I updated cordova to latest version (8) and added android platform latest @7.0.1 then admob plugin give this error:

```
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-admobpro': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '(myapppath)\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:648:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:553:33)
    at Object.parseElementtreeSync ( (myapppath) \platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\util\xml-helpers.js:180:27)
    at new AndroidManifest ( (myapppath) \platforms\android\cordova\lib\AndroidManifest.js:29:20)
    at AndroidProject.getPackageName (myapppath) \platforms\android\cordova\lib\AndroidProject.js:99:12)
    at Api.addPlugin ( (myapppath) \platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:223:57)
    at handleInstall (C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:594:10)
    at C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:357:28
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
(node:5328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ' (myapppath) \platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'
(node:5328) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was using another plugin 
[cordova-plugin-admob-free](https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free)
along with the ionic native for that plugin.

I did a demo for that and post it on github:
[ionic-admob-demo](https://github.com/MoAsmar/ionic-admob-demo)